# XSLT :Check if value is empty then remove the tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have Input XML. We are trying to remove such elements those are having empty and non-empty values. we have `<Item>` as repeated element. `<TermsCode>` is having empty and non-empty values for repeated item.

We have to remove such `<TermsCode>` empty tag after making check in XSLT IF it is empty. or if it is having value it should keep the tag. 
Similarly, we are trying to write for each  element involves in item node. if it is empty then remove. if not then should keep the tag in Output XML.

**INPUT XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SetupArCustomer>
   <Item>
      <Key>
         <Customer>0039069</Customer>
      </Key>
      <Name>ABC SOLUTIONS LLC</Name>
      <CreditLimit>0.0</CreditLimit>
      <PriceCode>WH</PriceCode>
      <Branch>NY</Branch>
      <TermsCode>00</TermsCode>
      </Item>
   <Item>
      <Key>
         <Customer>0039070</Customer>
      </Key>
      <Name>CCD WHOLESALE NY INC.</Name>
      <CreditLimit>0.0</CreditLimit>
      <PriceCode>HY</PriceCode>
      <Branch>NY</Branch>
      <TermsCode/>
     </Item>
   </SetupArCustomer>
```

**TRIED XSLT2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SetupArCustomer>
       <Item>
          <Key>
             <Customer>0039069</Customer>
          </Key>
          <Name>ABC SOLUTIONS LLC</Name>
          <CreditLimit>0.0</CreditLimit>
          <PriceCode>WH</PriceCode>
          <Branch>NY</Branch>
          <TermsCode>00</TermsCode>
          </Item>
       <Item>
          <Key>
             <Customer>0039070</Customer>
          </Key>
          <Name>CCD WHOLESALE NY INC.</Name>
          <CreditLimit>0.0</CreditLimit>
          <PriceCode>HY</PriceCode>
          <Branch>NY</Branch>
         </Item>
       </SetupArCustomer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove empty `TermsCode` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TermsCode[not(node())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To remove *any* empty child element of `Item`, change:

```
<xsl:template match="TermsCode[not(node())]"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="Item/*[not(node())]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I applied to  env <xsl:template match="Item/*[not(node())]"/>. it is working for us.